# cflayout of type accordion in coldfusion 11

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to use cflayout to create an accordion control on ColdFusion 11. Below is the code I am using:

```
<cflayout name="outerlayout" type="accordion" titlecollapse="true" width="150px"> 
    <cflayoutarea name="area1" collapsible="true" title="acc1"> 
        <h3>Area 1</h3> 
        <ul><li>sdfgsdfg</li><li>sdfgsdf</li></ul>
    </cflayoutarea>   
    <cflayoutarea name="area2" collapsible="true" title="acc2"> 
        <h3>Area 2</h3> 
        <ul><li>sdfgsdfg</li><li>sdfgsdf</li></ul>
        <ul><li>sdfgsdfg</li><li>sdfgsdf</li></ul> 
        <ul><li>sdfgsdfg</li><li>sdfgsdf</li></ul> 
    </cflayoutarea> 
</cflayout>
```

I have the following issues with the code:
 1. It displays same height for each accordion irrespective of their content.
 2. Unordered list doesn't get displayed as usual.
 3. I want all the accordions to be initially collapsed. I am not able to accomplish it.

Note: I know it's not wise to use `cflayout` of the ColdFusion. But anyway I want to use it.

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere? You already know what the problem is...`cflayout`. Don't use the ColdFusion UI elements. They are poorly implemented, outdated and woefully limited. Do it the right way by using a JS library like jQuery with jQuery UI. You will find it is easier to use and offers you more flexibility in terms of function and style. Also,  some may not be motivated to offer assistance when you admit you are doing something that maybe you shouldn't.

Comment: "Note: I know it's not wise to use cflayout of the ColdFusion. But anyway I want to use it."
It's difficult to answer your "question" then, because that's what the problem here is.

Comment: @AdamCameron. I wanted to use `cflayout` for accordion because it allows anchors in accordion header text. So, if some accordion is having no content, in that case we used to give a hyperlink to header text. Implementing that functionality using jQuery UI seems like a lot of work because jQuery accordion doesn't support accordion header text to be used as hyperlink.

Comment: Well what about Foundation or BootStrap or something like that that? The ColdFusion implementation won't do anything the popular libraries don't achieve cos all it is is a wrapper for an outdated version of ExtJS. A simple google of "html accordion" or "js accordion" should give you a multitude of better options not relying on obsolete technology like that which ColdFusion wraps up.

Comment: @AdamCameron I have finally switched to jQuery accordion. With few tweaks suggested by jQuery community I was able to get my job done.

Comment: Nice one. Don't forget to post an answer so others can benefit. It might also be helpful to donate some code to https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way, if you have the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally decided to switch to jQuery solution as the cflayout solution of ColdFusion seems to be very buggy. This is how I achieved my requirements using jquery.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Collapse content</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      active: false,
      collapsible: true,
      heightStyle: "content"
    });

    $("#accordion>h3>a").click(function(){
        var loc = $(this).prop("href");
        window.open(loc, '_blank');
    })
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3><a href="http://www.google.com">Section 1</a></h3>
  <div>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est. </p><p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

To solve my first issue we need to set `heightStyle` option to `"content"`. It ensures that the height of each accordion element is a according to content of its elements.

The jQuery accordion has no issues with unordered list.

Finally to make all the accordions collapsed initially, we just need to set `active` to `false`.

One more thing. I noted that jQuery accordion loads faster than the Coldfusion's one. Thanks [Adam Cameron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894061/adam-cameron) & [Scott Stroz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/789209/scott-stroz) for pushing me to go for jQuery solution.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your Issue #1:

The code for cflayout.js on ColdFusion 11 has the height for all accordion tabs hardcoded to 600. This results in either scrollbars or large blank spaces in each tab.

Edit the code at c:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE\scripts\ajax\package\cflayout.js, and delete Line 430 which reads:
 _85e.height=600;

You will need to flush the template and component caches after editing this code (in the Caching section of ColdFusion Administrator).